# PHP: Create a new class object directly from a string return value (string literal)

Tags: php, class, instantiation

Is there any possibility to create a new object by a string that is returned by a function or method in PHP? Like some escape method I do not know?

Non-working example:

```
new ($class->method())();
new "stringliteral"();
new ($class = $class->method())();
```

Comment: Why would you need to use a string literal? Why write `new "stringliteral"()` instead of `new stringliteral()`?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php for the ways to work with class and namespace names dynamically. It looks like they have to be in variables.

Comment: Why do you have to do it directly? Is your server running low on variables?

Comment: I do not have to do it directly. The question has a more 'informative' character.

Comment: Would be nice if you'd accept Barmar's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33299656/1402176

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
function makeRef($className) {
    return new ReflectionClass($className);
}
$obj = makeRef($class->method())->newInstance();
```

In PHP 5.4+ you can turn this into a one-liner:

```
$obj = (new ReflectionClass($class->method()))->newInstance();
```

Comment: Or if you prefer one-liners `$object = (new ReflectionClass($class->method()))->newInstance();`. I don't see why one wouldn't just use a variable tho?

Comment: @toster-cx I tried doing that but got a parse error. Maybe because I'm using PHP 5.3, I suspect it works in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Nice thought! Forgot Reflection. Thanks.

Comment: Although I do not know the syntax you are using. But since I use a static method now, I can use: `(new ReflectionMethod('class', 'method'))->invoke(null, 'param1')`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want dynamic class creation?
here is a read :
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch07_13.htm

While it is OK to invoke dynamic function, doing it for class seems to be  a stunt.

Comment: no. my question is, if it is possible to create a class directly from a string literal or return value without putting it into a variable before.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Assign the string to a variable then create object using that variable.

**Ex.**

```
<?php
class stringliteral{
  function __construct()
  {
    echo"called";
  }
}
function dumyFunc()
{
  return 'stringliteral';
}
$str=dumyFunc();
if(class_exists($str))
$obj=new $str();
?>
```

Comment: Please read the heading - "directly". I know that I can use a variable.

Comment: Errrr `Fatal error: Class 'stringliteral' not found` Think before you jump `new` instantiates an existing class!!

Comment: Now it will solve your requirements. check it once again

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ok so **test before you jump**, put an else on that if eg `else echo 'I didnt test this';` Also you have created the class, he wants to create the class Dynamically

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi: I suggest you delete your answer, because it absolutely doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly In my answer else statement is not strictly need also in the question doesn't  asked to create the class dynamically. He asked to create object

Comment: No, but if you ADD ONE, you will see that the IF will take the ELSE path as `if(class_exists($str))` **is false** ___I tested it___, _a rash and novel idea I grant you_

Comment: I have answered how to create an object by a string passed by function as stated in the question. I think these are enough for the given question. If user want he can add IF,ELSE IF,ELSE,.. whatever he want.

Comment: You are not getting it. Your code does not work. Test it and see